# Getting Image from MySQL into tableWidget in PyQt5

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have been able to get data from database and populate into the tableWidget, but the image column is not shown. I tried a code I found online and still, it didn't work. The image column in the database has the BLOB data type. Kindly assist in correcting my following code. Or you may want to advise and recommend another method other than the tableWidget

```
 def getPersData(self):
    con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="db")
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        query = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM persons")

        rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row_number, row_data in enumerate(rows):
        self.ui.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
        for column_number, column_data in enumerate(row_data):
            if column_number == 1:
                item = self.getImg(column_data)
                self.ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row_number, column_number, item)
            else:
                self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(column_data)))
    self.ui.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(100)
    self.ui.tableWidget.show()


def getImg(self, img):
    img_label = self.ui.label
    img_label.setText("")
    img_label.setScaledContents(True)
    pixmap = QPixmap()
    pixmap.loadFromData(img, "PNG")
    img_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
    return img_label
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic to use the bytes (in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63961383/6622587) I proposed to use base64 so I use it in this case as well) to build a QPixmap that can be converted into a QIcon that can be displayed in the QTableWidget:

```
for row_number, row_data in enumerate(rows):
    self.ui.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
    for column_number, column_data in enumerate(row_data):
        it = QTableWidgetItem()
        if column_number == 1:
            pixmap = QPixmap()
            pixmap.loadFromData(QByteArray.fromBase64(row_data))
            icon = QIcon(pixmap)
            it.setIcon(icon)
        else:
            it.setText(row_data)
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, it)
```